# WinError 10060 - sentinelsat library on python

Tags: python, proxy, sentinel, sentinelsat

I use sentinelsat library in python for some period of time without any problem at the company I work on. Suddenly, I got the following error that I have attached below. I have written a simple script of code to find the source of the error. My code just finds some images of Sentinel based on some criteria and downloads one of them (the username and password are declared but not shown). The problem occurs when  api.query is executed.

```
from datetime import date
import sentinelsat

api = sentinelsat.SentinelAPI(username, password)
start_date = date(2023, 12, 1)
end_date = date(2023, 12, 10)
platform_name = 'Sentinel-2'
product_type = 'S2MSI1C'  # Sentinel-2 Level-1C product

tile_coords = '30TVK'  # Replace this with the specific tile you want to download

# Define the search parameters for the specific tile
tile_query = f'tileid={tile_coords}'



# Search for available images based on the defined criteria
products = api.query(tileid = '30TVK',
                     date=(start_date, end_date),
                     platformname=platform_name,
                     producttype=product_type)

# for product_id, product_info in products.items():
#     print(product_info)
    

# Download the desired image (change product_id to the one you want to download)
# api.download(product_id)
```

The error I encountered is:

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001C910FAC850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060]

After some search (https://github.com/sentinelsat/sentinelsat/issues/542), I found that it may be related to the network. I am not familiar with proxies. I added the two following lines but there is still no improvement.

```
import os
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = 'http://10.10.1.10:3128'
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = 'http://10.10.1.10:1080'
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default API that `sentinelsat` connects to has been shut down ([source](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/news/News01146)). Your only option is to change to a different national mirror that exposes a DHuS compatible API.

The successor is the Copernicus Data Space Ecosystem that uses an API that `sentinelsat` is not (yet) compatible with. See this Github issue for further discussion: https://github.com/sentinelsat/sentinelsat/issues/583

Answer (score 0):

I have attached a link that includes a tutorial about the new Copernicus Data Space Ecosystem (how to download data from it):  https://dataspace.copernicus.eu/news/2023-9-28-accessing-sentinel-mission-data-new-copernicus-data-space-ecosystem-apis
You need to create a new account and use your credentials.

There is also a jupyter notebook with thorough instructions.

https://github.com/eu-cdse/notebook-samples/blob/c0e0ade601973c5d4e4bf66a13c0b76ebb099805/sentinelhub/migration_from_scihub_guide.ipynb

The code could be found below. Only the first product will be downloaded. Do not forget to change username and password.

```
# Utilities
import os
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import requests

start_date = "2022-06-01"
end_date = "2022-06-10"
data_collection = "SENTINEL-2"
aoi = "POLYGON((4.220581 50.958859,4.521264 50.953236,4.545977 50.906064,4.541858 50.802029,4.489685 50.763825,4.23843 50.767734,4.192435 50.806369,4.189689 50.907363,4.220581 50.958859))'"

json = requests.get(f"https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/odata/v1/Products?$filter=Collection/Name eq '{data_collection}' and OData.CSC.Intersects(area=geography'SRID=4326;{aoi}) and ContentDate/Start gt {start_date}T00:00:00.000Z and ContentDate/Start lt {end_date}T00:00:00.000Z").json()
catalog = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json['value'])
# catalog_sel = catalog.head(3)

data = {
    "client_id": "cdse-public",
    "username": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
    "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "grant_type": "password",
    }
try:
    r = requests.post("https://identity.dataspace.copernicus.eu/auth/realms/CDSE/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    data=data,
    )
    r.raise_for_status()
except Exception as e:
    raise Exception(
        f"Keycloak token creation failed. Reponse from the server was: {r.json()}"
        )

keycloak_token = r.json()["access_token"]

product_i = catalog_sel.Id.iloc[0]
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'Authorization': f'Bearer {keycloak_token}'})
url = f"https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/odata/v1/Products({product_i})/$value"
print(url)

# url = f"https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/odata/v1/Products("+product+")/$value"
response = session.get(url, allow_redirects=False)                  
while response.status_code in (301, 302, 303, 307):
    url = response.headers['Location']
    response = session.get(url, allow_redirects=False)

file = session.get(url, verify=False, allow_redirects=True)
file_name = f"outputs/product_{product_i}.zip"

with open(file_name, 'wb') as p:
    p.write(file.content)
```